# strcat in while

Tags: c, postgresql

i have to make a program which can accept input like this:

```
2012-01-20 10:50:52 127.0.0.1(via UDP: [127.0.0.1]:65008->[0.0.0.0]:0) TRAP, SNMP v1, community telros
        SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.3.1.1 Enterprise Specific Trap (1) Uptime: 73 days, 21:16:00.11

2012-01-20 10:50:53 127.0.0.1(via UDP: [127.0.0.1]:57487->[0.0.0.0]:0) TRAP, SNMP v1, community telros
        SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.3.1.1 Enterprise Specific Trap (1) Uptime: 73 days, 21:16:01.15

2012-01-20 10:50:54 127.0.0.1(via UDP: [127.0.0.1]:34207->[0.0.0.0]:0) TRAP, SNMP v1, community telros
        SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.3.1.1 Enterprise Specific Trap (1) Uptime: 73 days, 21:16:01.92
```

and then put it into Postgres: get two lines devided by empty (`\n`) line and put it into db table.

what i'm trying to do is:

```
const char *conninfo;
const char *paramValues[1]; 
char *str;
char *sql;
...
while(fgets(str, 126, stdin)) {

        if (0 != strcmp(str,"\n")){
        strcat(sql,str);
        }else{
        paramValues[0] = (const char *)sql;
        res = PQexecParams(conn,
            "insert into traps (trap_content, trap_timestamp) values ($1, localtimestamp);",
            1,
            NULL,
            paramValues,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            1);
        sql = "";
        }
    }
```

but `paramValues[0]` seems to be empty on insert and empty line appears in the table.

how can i get two strings before the empty one in `paramValues[0]`?
i'm not good in C, so sorry if it's silly question =)

Comment: @Mahesh i'm reading input line by line, so for first two lines `if` satisfies and `strcat` should be called, then, on `\n` line data must be inserted in the database. i'm compating with `\n` cause it's a content of my 'empty' line

Comment: are you sure you are getting new line in the string ?

Comment: @k102 - Show how you have declared `sql`, `str`, `paramValues`. With that said, for concatenation to take place it should initially be null terminated in your case( i.e., `sql` should have at least one termination character 0. If not concatenation will not take place ). Assuming `sql` does not have anything initially. Also `""` != `'\0'`.

Comment: @dicaprio, yes, even tried manual input.

Comment: @Mahesh edited to show declaration

Comment: @k102 str, sql are just pointers to char type. Have you allocated memory for them using malloc ? I don't see any need to malloc, just allocate them on stack.

Comment: I would suggest reading up on pointers and fundamental string handling in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
sql = "";
```

will cause the char* variable 'sql' to point at the address of the string literal "".  It's incorrect to then call strcat(sql,str) with sql now pointing to the address of this literal; that could even segfault.  Try instead:

```
strcpy(sql, "");
```

or equivalently

```
sql[0] = 0
```

Also, you don't show where 'sql' is defined, but it has to point to a buffer big enough to hold as many adjacent lines as you expect to encounter.

Comment: @Mahesh: Nobody said that either. strcpy(sql, "") is equivalent to sql[0]=0. The former is just a slower way of doing the latter.

Comment: @Lundin `strcpy(sql,"")` is **not** equivalent to `sql[0]=0;` If you said the same, then ignore my comment :)

Comment: thanks! i had no segfault somehow, but now it works as i need to

Comment: @Mahesh: It is. Why wouldn't it be? ISO 9899:1999 7.21.2.3: "The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including the terminating null character) into the array pointed to by s1." There is an empty string in this case, so nothing but the null character is copied.